# Как обратиться к нужному окну, если заголовки у всех одинаковы?

Tags: c#, winapi

Если окно одно, то я  его успешно нахожу и нормально обращаюсь через `FindWindow`

```
        // Get a handle to an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        // Activate an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
            // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
            IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame", "Калькулятор");

            // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
            if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
                return;
            }

            // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
            // a set of calculations.
            SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("111");
            SendKeys.SendWait("*");
            SendKeys.SendWait("11");
            SendKeys.SendWait("=");
        }
```

но если запустить вторую копию программы то у этих окон одинаковые классы и заголовки и через `FindWindow` не находит. Какие еще есть способы? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось через `EnumWindows`, готовая реализация:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        // Get a handle to an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        // Activate an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool IsWindowVisible ( IntPtr hWnd );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        List<IntPtr> ListHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

        //перед нажатием кнопки запускаем несколько калькуляторов 
        private void btnSearchHwnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnumWindows((hWnd, lParam) =>
            {
                if ((IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) != 0) && GetWindowText(hWnd).StartsWith("Калькулятор"))
                {
                    ListHandles.Add(hWnd);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(hWnd.ToString());
                }
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) + 1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
            len = GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, len);
            return sb.ToString(0, len);
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
            // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
            IntPtr calculatorHandle = ListHandles[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

            if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
                return;
            }

            //выводим на передний фон окно именно того калькулятора, 
            //дескриптор которого выбрали в listBox1, что и требовалось
            SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);

            //Делаем с нужным окном что хотим
            SendKeys.SendWait("111");
            SendKeys.SendWait("*");
            SendKeys.SendWait("11");
            SendKeys.SendWait("=");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основным способом по-любому будет `FindWindow()`, если вам нужно, чтобы программа не запускалась, если копия уже запущена, то используйте мютексы. В Delphi на чистом WinApi это выглядит так:

```
var
HM:Thandle;
begin
 HM := OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, false, 'MyProg'); // ищем мютекс "MyProg"
  if HM = 0 then
// резервируем мютекс "MyProg", если такового не найдено.
    HM := CreateMutex(nil, false, 'MyProg') else application.Terminate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Найти handle окна можно стандартными средствами **.NET**'а. Обратите внимание на класс [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) (В частности на его свойства [`MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx), [`MainWindowTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) и [`ProcessName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx). А также статические методы [`GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) и [`GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx))

Ипользуя вышеперечисленное, несложно найти все интересующие окна:

```
IntPtr[] handles = Process.GetProcessesByName("requiredProcess")
                     .Where(process => process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                     .Select(process => process.MainWindowHandle)
                     .ToArray();
```

После этого можно "общаться" со всеми найденными окнами.
Второй вариант в Вашей ситуации - закрыть все "лишние" окна, оставив одно. Закрыть главное окно процесса можно с помощью метода [`CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx).